# MATLAB sort() vs Numpy argsort() - how to match results?

Tags: python, matlab, sorting, numpy

I'm porting a MATLAB code to Python's Numpy.

In MATLAB (Octave, actually), I have something like:

```
>> someArr = [9, 8, 7, 7]
>> [~, ans] = sort(someArr, 'descend')
   ans =
   1   2   3   4
```

So in Numpy I'm doing:

```
>>> someArr = np.array([9, 8, 7, 7])
>>> np.argsort(someArr)[::-1]
array([0, 1, 3, 2])
```

I got `1, 2, 3, 4` in MATLAB while `0, 1, 3, 2` on Numpy, and I need `0, 1, 2, 3` on Numpy.

I believe it due to the sorting algorithm used in each function, But I checked and it looks like both are using "quicksort" (see [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) and [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/96656-what-type-of-sort-does-the-sort-function-in-matlab-perform)).

How can I match the Numpy's solution to the MATLAB one?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You can go from zero-indexing to one-indexing by adding one. The reversed order is nothing you can expect to not happen with a sorting algorithm.

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my question. The 0-index to 1-index doesn't matter to me, only the indices order.

Comment: Does it matter what order the two 7 values are put in? They're both the same value...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to make this work, we need to be a little bit clever.  `numpy` doesn't have the `'descend'` analog.  You're mimicking it by reversing the results of the sort (which is ultimately you're undoing).

I'm not sure how `matlab` accomplishes it, but they claim to use a [stable variant of quicksort](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/an-adventure-of-sortsbehind-the-scenes-of-a-matlab-upgrade.html).  Specifically, for descending sorts:

> If the flag is 'descend', the output is reversed just before being returned. After the reversal, we ran the index vector sorts to restore stability.

It appears that `octave` follows suit here.

Since their sort is stable, you have the guarantee that the order of equal values in the input will be preserved in the output.  `numpy` on the other hand makes no such guarantees for it's quicksort.  If we want a stable sort in numpy, we need to use `mergesort`:

```
>>> np.argsort(someArr, kind='mergesort')
array([2, 3, 1, 0])
```

Ok, this output makes sense.  `someArr[2] == someArr[3]` and the third element comes before the fourth so it is sensible that `2` would be before `3` in the output (without a guaranteed stable sorting algorithm, we couldn't make this claim).  Now comes the clever stepping... You want the "descending" values, but rather than reversing the output of `argsort`, why don't we negate the input?  That will have the effect of larger numbers sorting before than their lower counterparts just as a descending sort would do...

```
>>> np.argsort(-someArr, kind='quicksort')
array([0, 1, 2, 3])
```

Now we're talkin!  And since mergesort is guaranteed to be stable, elements (with equal values) which appear at lower indices will appear in the output first -- Just like matlab/octave.  Nice.

Comment: Great! Thanks! It works, though I don't fully understand it. Can you please specify how does negating the input array affect the sorting?

Comment: Think of it this way ... If you have an array `[3, 2, 5, 7, 9]` and you sort it descending (`sorted(array, reverse=True)`), you'll get `[9, 7, 5, 3, 2]`.  BUT, you'll also get that result if you you:  `sorted(array, key=lambda x: -x)`.  We're doing the same thing here... `argsort` is basically just a sort of the indices with the key function returning the value.  If we negate the value, we reverse the sort (just like in the previous example).

Comment: Sure, but why `np.argsort(-someArr)` and `np.argsort(someArr)[::-1]` give different results?

Comment: @galah92 -- Maybe it's easier if you think about a limiting case... Consider `someArr = [1, 1, 1, 1]`.  Assuming a stable sorting algorithm, `np.argsort(-someArr)` will give `[0, 1, 2, 3]`.  `np.argsort(someArry)` will give the same thing so when you reverse it it'll give `[3, 2, 1, 0]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose between different sorting algorithms. Changing it to `heapsort` worked for me:

```
>> np.argsort(someArr, kind="heapsort")[::-1]
array([0, 1, 2, 3], dtype=int32)
```

Edit: This only works for a few test cases I looked at. For `[9, 8, 7, 7, 4, 1, 1]` it stops working. My answer is probably not a good solution.

Comment: It might work on _this_ input, but it isn't guarnateed to work on _all_ input.

Answer (score 0):

## try this

```
np.argsort(dataset,axis=-1,kind='stable')
```

Comment: Can you please edit your post to explain your answer. Why is it better than the other answers?